# Variable not defined problem with option explicit macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code which works with a simple sheet. If I try and incorporate it into my macro, which is option explicit then it throws an error that variable x is not defined.

Have tried various Dim as but without success. New to this so I assume I am missing something, probably fairly obvious to you guys

```
Sub FillDuplicates()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column A

For x = 1 To lastrow
    If Cells(x, 1).Value = 0 Then 'Find initial 0 value

            If Cells(x + 1, 1).Value = 0 Then 'Compares cell against previous cell
                Cells(x + 1, 1).Value = "" 'If matches, sets value as nothing
            End If

    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

This identifies where there are a number of consecutive 0 values in the column. It then retains the first and deletes the others, then moves on to the next group and so on.

Comment: x looks like an integer to me. So try `Dim x as Interger` or possibly long, depending on how many rows you expect there to be. Integer has a Max of ~32000 if I remember correctly

Comment: The `x` goes from 1 to `lastrow` where `lastrow` is `Long`. So `x` also should be `Long`. So `Dim x As Long` before `For x = 1 To lastrow`.

Comment: Definitely `Long` as it's using row numbers which can exceed the limit of an `Integer`.  Also because `lastrow` is defined as `Long`, so makes sense that a variable that steps through each value in `lastrow` should also be `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas before me: 
You have to define the `x` variable:

```
Sub FillDuplicates()
Dim lastrow As Long

Dim x as Integer 'if you have more 32767 rows to check then use double which is good for 1.79769313486231570E+308

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column A

For x = 1 To lastrow
    If Cells(x, 1).Value = 0 Then 'Find initial 0 value

            If Cells(x + 1, 1).Value = 0 Then 'Compares cell against previous cell
                Cells(x + 1, 1).Value = "" 'If matches, sets value as nothing
            End If

    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

This should solve the problem :)

Comment: S/he means x, not i. Basically, the error occurs because you're using x as your loop counter: but you have not Dim'med it. You need to declare every variable you use, and loop counter variables are no exception. Lonolian is correct, but just made a typo, using "i" instead of "x".

Comment: Thank you Darren Bartup-Cook and Chris Melville